# Show different text after on click event in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt, I have three button: AA, BB, CC. The default button is AA when you open the page, I want to let user able to click three button (AA/BB/CC) and show different plans in text shown using vuejs. Here is my html element

```
<div v-for="i in ZZ"  v-if="{id: i.id}">
<button @click="i.show_1 = !i.show_1"> AA</button>
<button @click="i.show_2 = !i.show_2"> BB</button>
<button @click="i.show_3 = !i.show_3"> CC</button>
<p>shown in here! {{i.hub_des_1}}</p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
export default {
    return{
        show_1 = true,
        show_2 = false,
        show_3 = false
    }
    data() {
        ZZ: [
            {  id:1,
               hub_des_1: show this1
            },
            {  id:2,
               hub_des_1: show this2
            }
            {  id:3,
               hub_des_1: show this3
            }
```

]
}

If I click AA is correct, the text will be
"shown in here! show this1" //
On the other hand when I click BB, the text will change to
"shown in here! show this2"

Anything wrong, how can I do shown based on what I clicked?

Comment: Why not have a `selected` and update that one with something simple like `selected = 'show this1'` once you click on a button? Do you even need a loop here? What is your `v-if` doing here too? Where are your `show_1` states btw? The `return` should be nested inside of `data()`. I recommend reading a bit more the documentation. I'll maybe send you a code example later on too!

Comment: I might need a loop cause I have to show 10 more items, but let me try what you just said now first : ))